# understanding how nested if statement effects incrementing for loop

Tags: javascript

trying to make sure I understand what is happening in this FCC activity. I'm confused as to why we're using keys.length as opposed to collection.length for iterating over the collection Array of objects. The keys.length for this example is only 1 and the collection array is 3, so how do we reach the whole array? Is it because the if statement inside the loop is returning false, therefore not incrementing the i value until the condition returns true? Thank you in advance for helping a noob out! :)

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  let keys = Object.keys(source)
  let arr = collection.filter(function(obj) {
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(keys[i]) || obj[keys[i]] !== source[keys[i]]) {
        return false
      }
    }
    return true
  })
  
  console.log(keys.length)
  // Only change code below this line


  // Only change code above this line
  return arr;
}

whatIsInAName([{
  first: "Romeo",
  last: "Montague"
}, {
  first: "Mercutio",
  last: null
}, {
  first: "Tybalt",
  last: "Capulet"
}], {
  last: "Capulet"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things happening here. 1. `collection.filter(...)` is calling the function in the parentheses on each element in `collection`. 2. Within this function, a for-loop iterates over each element in the array given by `Object.keys(source)`. `Object.keys(...)` returns an array consisting of all keys in the object you provide to this function, which in your case is `source`. So there are in fact two loops.

You could have a look at what `filter` does [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and especially the examples. Also you can check what `keys` [does](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and also make sure you understand the difference between arrays and objects in javascript.

Comment: Thanks! So could I achieve the same result using a nested for loop instead of filter? With the outter loop using collection.length and the inner using keys.length? I def need to become more comfortable with objects, they are new to me. Thanks for taking time to help me out, I appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, you could use a for-loop instead of `filter`. But `filter` is more common for this situation and communcats your intention better to others reading your code. `filter` is basically saying: Look at all elements of an array and put only those in another array (in your case `arr`) for which the function given as a parameter to `filter`(a callback) returns true.